# how to write Query for select statment where column IN

Tags: asp.net, sql

i have write an Query where the  table  name  is **student**  has  columns, **class, names,  Language**

now i need  to write an single query where

`class='10', names ="kiran, manju, ram , peter",   Language='english'`

how do I write a Query where one column wil have multiple values?

Looking frwd  for  solution

thank you

Comment: What's in the "names" column?  A single name first name, a complete name with first and last name, or a comma-delimited list of names?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the "IN" Keyword

```
SELECT * FROM students 
WHERE class='10'
AND Names IN ('kiran', 'manju', 'ram' , 'peter')
AND Language = 'english'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM student 
WHERE class = 10 
AND language = 'english' 
AND (names = 'kiran' OR names = 'manju' OR names = 'ram' OR names = 'peter')
```

Answer (score 0):

you were almost there.

```
select * from student where  class='10' AND/OR names in ('kiran', 'manju', 'ram' , 'peter') AND/OR Language='english'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are hard coding the values for the IN clause, previous answers are good.  If you are collecting the values dynamically, you will need to use parameters: http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/116/Parameterized-IN-clauses-with-ADO.NET-and-LINQ